# Can't display a checkerboard with array using ascii table

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2013, ascii

I'm a newbie in c++. I have this homework and I can't display my checkerboard with a `for` loop! The board must look like the image below
each case case 8 caracter on 4 colomn and 2 row:

[image]

```
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

const int up = 80, down = 72, left = 77, right = 75, HD = 73, HG = 71, BG = 79, BD = 81;
const int NB_COL = 12, NB_LIG = 8;

using namespace std;

struct Mat_Pos_s 
{
    int lig;
    int Col;
};


// Matrice composant le damier du jeu :
// 0==Normal(white), 1==$$$$ hidden, 2==$$$$ visible, 3==grey, 4== black wall

int Mat[NB_LIG][NB_COL] =
{
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4 },
    { 0, 0, 4, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1 },
    { 0, 0, 4, 1, 4, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 4, 1 },
    { 1, 0, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0 },
    { 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 4, 1, 4, 0, 4, 0 },
    { 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 0 },
    { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};

void main(void)
{
    Mat_Pos_s Depart; 
    Mat_Pos_s Arrive; 

    char piece = 178, q = 176;
    char a = 201, b = 200, c = 203, d = 202, e = 187, f = 188 ;

    gotoxy(10, 2);
    for (int y = 0; y < NB_LIG; y++)
    {
        cout << endl ;

        for (int x = 0; x < NB_COL; x++)
        {

            if (Mat[y][x] == 0)

            {
                cvm_SetColor(BLEU);

                cout << piece << piece << piece << piece << " " <<endl;

                cout << piece << piece << piece << piece << " ";
            }
            else if (Mat[y][x] == 1)
            {
                cvm_SetColor(BLEU); 
                cout << piece << piece << piece << piece << " " <<endl ;
                cout << piece << piece << piece << piece << " ";
            }
            else
            {
                cvm_SetColor(NOIR);

                cout << piece << piece << piece << piece << " " <<endl;
                cout << piece << piece << piece << piece << " ";
            }
        }

        cout << endl ;
    }
    _getch()
}
```

Comment: Which compiler are you on?

Comment: If `0` is meant to be white, then why are are you using `BLEU` instead of `BLANC`?

Comment: right now the color doesn't matter I'm just trying to make the board at it original state which is black walls and white cases with the cursor at the original position

Comment: so grey and $$$ appear as white cases since they are still hidden

Comment: @Johnny _asap_ is just braze faced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each cell is four characters wide by two lines high, you're going to have to do something a bit trickier than:

```
cout << piece << piece << piece << piece << " " <<endl;
cout << piece << piece << piece << piece << " ";
```

for each cell, since you need to do each *line* and a line is only half a cell high.

Hence your loops will need to be something like (pseudo-code):

```
for row = 1 to maxrow:
    for height = 1 to 2:
        for col = 1 to maxcol:
            set color
            output four copies of piece, no newline.
        output newline
```

That way, you do each row in two passes, one for each line, like this (for a 3x2 matrix using lower-case followed by upper-case for sequencing):

```
+----+----+----+
|abcd|efgh|ijkl|
|mnop|qrst|uvwx|
+----+----+----+
|yzAB|CDEF|GHIJ|
|KLMN|OPQR|STUV|
+----+----+----+
```

---

The following code shows something more akin to what you need, with a blank line between each two-line-high row to emphasise the spread:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define NB_ROW 8
#define NB_COL 12
int Mat[NB_ROW][NB_COL] = {
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4 },
    { 0, 0, 4, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1 },
    { 0, 0, 4, 1, 4, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 4, 1 },
    { 1, 0, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0 },
    { 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 4, 1, 4, 0, 4, 0 },
    { 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 0 },
    { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};

int main(){
    for (int row = 0; row < NB_ROW; row++) {
        for (int line = 0; line < 2; line++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < NB_COL; col++) {
                switch (Mat[row][col]) {
                    case 0: cout << "WHIT "; break;
                    case 1: cout << "HIDN "; break;
                    case 2: cout << "VSBL "; break;
                    case 3: cout << "GREY "; break;
                    case 4: cout << "BLAK "; break;
                }
            }
            cout << '\n';
        }
        cout << '\n'; // This one's for the spread.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT BLAK WHIT WHIT HIDN 
WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT BLAK WHIT WHIT HIDN 

WHIT WHIT BLAK BLAK WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT BLAK WHIT BLAK 
WHIT WHIT BLAK BLAK WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT BLAK WHIT BLAK 

WHIT WHIT BLAK HIDN BLAK WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT BLAK HIDN 
WHIT WHIT BLAK HIDN BLAK WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT BLAK HIDN 

WHIT WHIT BLAK HIDN BLAK WHIT WHIT BLAK BLAK WHIT BLAK HIDN 
WHIT WHIT BLAK HIDN BLAK WHIT WHIT BLAK BLAK WHIT BLAK HIDN 

HIDN WHIT BLAK BLAK BLAK HIDN BLAK WHIT BLAK WHIT BLAK WHIT 
HIDN WHIT BLAK BLAK BLAK HIDN BLAK WHIT BLAK WHIT BLAK WHIT 

HIDN WHIT HIDN HIDN WHIT HIDN BLAK HIDN BLAK WHIT BLAK WHIT 
HIDN WHIT HIDN HIDN WHIT HIDN BLAK HIDN BLAK WHIT BLAK WHIT 

HIDN WHIT HIDN WHIT WHIT WHIT BLAK BLAK BLAK WHIT BLAK WHIT 
HIDN WHIT HIDN WHIT WHIT WHIT BLAK BLAK BLAK WHIT BLAK WHIT 

HIDN HIDN WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT 
HIDN HIDN WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT WHIT
```

Comment: so height replace cout <<endl?

Comment: @Johnny: sort of. You can't do an `endl` in the top left cell to do the bottom half of it, since there's no way to get back up to the top half of the second cell in that row (unless you start fiddling around with cursor movements. So the best bet is to do the whole first line of the first row, followed by `endl`, then the second line of the first row. Then go on to the second row and do the same thing.